# Move spam from dovecot public folders

Tags: centos, sendmail, dovecot, spamassassin, procmail

I have set up Dovecot with public folders on a CentOS 6-server, with sendmail and spamassassin. I'm getting a lot of spam in both public folders and in the users inboxes.
I want spamassassin / procmail to move the email marked as SPAM in a folders called SPAM: One public SPAM-folder (for all the public folders) , and one for every user.

How can I do this with spamassassin and procmail?

Comment: Hi Andy, we generally frown upon 'How do I do this?' questions where the asker has not indicated what they have tried on their own. Have you googled this already? What other things have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I understand. I have already tried different approaches that works on the user's folder, but haven't found any documentation for dovecot's public folders. This works for user folders: (/etc/procmailrc) `* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
probably-spam`

Comment: The top Google hit is http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Public -- did you read that?  Is your configuration similar?  How are you invoking Procmail for the public folders?  You will need to add more details in order for this question to be answerable.

Comment: Yes, that is the setup we are using. I'm invoking procmail through /etc/procmailrc. It looks like I can use something similiar to this: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/procmail.

Comment: So does that mean that you solved your problem already?

Comment: No, I don't know how to make rules that separates mail to public folders and mail to users. I'm starting to believe this is not possible, since procmail don't know if the mail is going to a user, or a public folder..